# Why is toggling div label not working within my code?

Tags: jquery

I want to toggle the label of a button with the help of jQuery.

This works on jsfiddle: [jsfiddle example](https://jsfiddle.net/d81vk734/)

```js
$("#filter_button").on("click", function(){
  if ( $("#filter_button_inner").text() ==="close" ){
     $("#filter_button_inner").text("open")
  }
  else{
     $("#filter_button_inner").text("close")
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="#left-panel" id="filter_button" data-shadow="false" data-iconshadow="false" >
  <div id="filter_button_inner" style="position:absolute;right:90px;margin-top:7px;margin-left:10px;border: 1px solid #ccc;padding:5px 20px;color:#10225A;font-weight:bold;border-radius: 5px;">open</div>
</a>
```

However, inside my application it does not. Running the same jQuery version and everything else is working.

What could be the issue here?

Comment: Any console errors?

Comment: worked on my page too

Comment: Any console error? Is jQuery correctly loaded? Is your click event executed? ...

Comment: No console errors:  http://staging.www.de.watchgurus.de/rolex/ andy:newpw2

Comment: I can't seem to find filter button in that site.

Comment: Only on mobile (or simulator) within the header, the button "open"

Comment: "What could be the issue" - 1 you're loading jquery after your script (would give error) 2 you have more than one #filter_button 3 you don't have any #filter_button 4 your script runs before the button exists 5 you late-load/dynamically-load the the filter_button so it doesn't exist when the code runs (similar to 4 but loaded dynamically).  Put your script inside `$(function() { /* here */ });` if that doesn't work, use `$(document).on("click", "#filter_button", function ...`

Comment: Thank you! No.4 fixed it. The script was before the button.

Comment: Glad you got it sorted - this is normally fixed by putting inside jquery doc ready `$(function() { `